# Need to hold the batch file completion, until the OSQL Command completes

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file, which executes a OSQl Command - which inturns exeutes a sql package.
The sql package takes 10min to execute, however the batch job completes in 10 sec.

Is there a way to hold back the Job , until the osql command succeeds?
I can add a wait time, which will work, but I am looking for some other options.

```
C:\>osql -S "EmployeeDB" -E -b -n -Q"exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'Name'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
start "" /w osql -S "EmployeeDB" -E -b -n -Q"exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'Name'"
```